# Determine button clicked for modal manipulation

Tags: javascript, angular, zurb-foundation

I have 2 buttons for which I want to call same modal but the text on the modal should be changed depending on which button was clicked. How do I do that please?

```
 <div>
    <a class="button" data-open="new-modal" 
     (click)="confirmModal(studentInfo)>Edit</a>

   <a class="button" data-open="new-modal"    
     (click)="confirmModal(studentInfo.id)>Delete</a>
 </div>
```

Modal

```
   <div class="reveal" data-reveal id="new-modal">
      <h5>Edit Student Info?</h5> // I want to add "Delete student info 
        here too"

      <div class="secondary button-group">
        <a class="button" href="#">Yes</a>
        <a class="button" href="#">No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which modal are you using?

Comment: foundation zurb modal https://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/modal @David

Comment: try passing the id and message to display as parameters in the confirmModal function and then in the function target the id and change the inner html text of the element in this case the h5 element of the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass a second parameter to your `confirmModal()` function, and store the content in a variable accessible by the modal within your ts or js code, and use this variable to load relevant configuration in your modal

Answer (score 0):

I have done bootstrap modal in different page means modal in another page(modal.html) and button in different page(career.php) it's working but same modal i want to link for multiple buttons. How to do that i am not getting

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $('#btnModal') .click(function(){
            //using ajaz post
            $.post('modal.html' ,function(xx){
                $('#tmpModal').html(xx) //fill div tmpmodal with modal.html content..!!
                //calling modal
                $('#testModal').modal('show');
            })
        })
    });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="testModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
                <h4>Apply Now</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Role</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Dest" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Full Name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Phone</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Comment</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Upload File</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="contact_send();">SEND</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```